# Should gravitational waves quantize similar to photons?

Tags: frequency, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, wavelength, carrier-particles

A single photon's energy is given by $E=hf$. This is also generalized to massive particles as $\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$ or $E = \sqrt{m_0^2c^4 + (hc/\lambda)^2}$ (they're equivalent for photons).

Having already measured gravitational wave frequencies, should we expect this to apply to quantizing gravitational waves? Or is there some reason to expect them to be lower energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full quantum theory of photons contains not only the expression for energy, but interaction terms, propagation, etc. The energy of a gravitational wave is indeed proportional to its frequency, but constructing a full quantum-theory for gravity using the conventional tools (QFT) is problematic (in technical terms- it is nonrenormalizable). Possible solutions to this include String Theory.

Comment: Is it proportional by the Planck Constant? Or some other constant?